# Table doesn't center

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am having trouble centering some table in a text. I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize, draftthesis]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath} %uso de equaciones
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{rotating} %para rotar la hoja y tabla 
\usepackage{booktabs} %hacer tablas 
\usepackage{adjustbox} %ajustar tabla a hoja
\usepackage{slashbox,multirow} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Appendix: Tables}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Ln Diff. Exchange rate tests}
\label{table:Diff. Exchange}
\begin{threeparttable}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}\\ 
%%% TABLE CONTENT
\end{tabular}}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[$\dagger$] Statistic for the series.
\item[$\ddagger$] Statistic for the squared residuals.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

But I have no centering table as you can see in the image. I tried different solutions referenced here. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Greetings! Your code doesn't provide any actual table contents; hence, it's not possible to evaluate what may be going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your not compiling code I would say: Do not use `\scalebox{0.8}{`.

See the following **compiling** MWE (I added dummy table and the missing command to end document):

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize, draftthesis]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath} %uso de equaciones
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{rotating} %para rotar la hoja y tabla 
\usepackage{booktabs} %hacer tablas 
\usepackage{adjustbox} %ajustar tabla a hoja
\usepackage{slashbox,multirow} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Appendix: Tables}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Ln Diff. Exchange rate tests}
\label{table:Diff. Exchange}
\begin{threeparttable}
%\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}\\ 
test & test & test & test & test\\
test & test & test & test & test\\
test & test & test & test & test\\
\end{tabular}%}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[$\dagger$] Statistic for the series.
\item[$\ddagger$] Statistic for the squared residuals.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]